# Can't deploy Hololens project with IL2CPP Error SuppressSystemOverlays

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, hololens, mrtk, il2cpp

I need some help because I can't deploy my app on Hololens since I've updated Holotoolkit to MRTK ; Unity 2017.4 to 2019.2 ; Visual Studio 2017 to 2019

I think it's IL2CPP problem...I can build in Unity without any error message.
I can build in VS.
But I can't deploy.
When I deploy with 'Start without debugging', I have this error :

```
Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State    Suppression State
Warning    C4973    'Windows::UI::ViewManagement::IApplicationView2::SuppressSystemOverlays::set': marked as deprecated    TestMRTKV2    D:\TestMRTKV2\TestMRTKV2\Build\TestMRTKV2\App.cpp    26        
Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State    Suppression State
Message        Message: 'Use the TryEnterFullScreen method and IsFullScreenMode property instead of SuppressSystemOverlays. For more info, see MSDN.'    TestMRTKV2    D:\TestMRTKV2\TestMRTKV2\Build\TestMRTKV2\App.cpp    26
```

I see this on Microsoft doc :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.suppresssystemoverlays

What I'm supposed to do is:

> SuppressSystemOverlays may be altered or unavailable for releases
>   after Windows 10. Instead, use TryEnterFullScreenMode and
>   FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.

But I don't know what is the complete instruction to do this, I'm not a developper and I'm afraid of making everything crash !!!

Thanks a lot

[Screenshot of Visual Studio with error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2as4r.png)

Comment: There are no Error Messages from your description and the screenshot, but in general, the error messages should be displayed when the deployment fails. 
Since the development of HoloLens apps requires the cooperation from multiple parties, including Unity, VS, MRTK SDK and so one. The cause of this result is uncertain. 
I would recommended that checking the latest MRTK for testing in your development environment to narrow down this issue, the step-by-step guide please see:https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html.

Comment: Thanks @Hernando-MSFT for your answer. I've made all the things that are recommended by MRTK guide. This is why I've posted my question here...

Comment: So the new project you created following the official tutorial works fine?